# how to detect an element inside a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to detect the drawn elements inside the canvas (for example: every slice in the pie) to put a click event on them later, but it seems not to be an easy task, I think the math would be the best way to carry it out, but where should I start.

Please Help me to find a solution for this.

here is the demo:
[outer link](https://jsfiddle.net/4v760pec/1/)

code is:

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #myCanvas{
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
    </html>

    class Piechart{
    constructor(){
      this.options = arguments[0];
      this.canvas = arguments[0].canvas;
      this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
      if(this.options.colors){
        this.colors = arguments[0].colors;
      }
      else if (!this.options.colors){
        this.colors = [
          "#fde23e",
          "#f16e23",
          "#57d9ff",
          "#937e88",
          '#2fe678',
          '#228888',
          '#b111c1'
        ];
      }
      this.donut_hole = 0.5;
    }

    drawPie(){
      var total_value = 0;
      var color_index = 0;
      for(var categ in this.options.data){
        var val = this.options.data[categ];
        total_value += val;
      }

      var start_angle = 0;
      for(var categ in this.options.data){
        var val = this.options.data[categ];
        var slice_angle = 2*Math.PI*val/total_value;

        this.drawPieSlice(
          this.ctx,
          this.canvas.width/2,
          this.canvas.height/2,
          Math.min(this.canvas.width/2,this.canvas.height/2),
          start_angle,
          start_angle+slice_angle,
          this.colors[color_index%this.colors.length]
        );

        start_angle += slice_angle;
        color_index++;
      }
    }

    drawPieSlice(){
      arguments[0].fillStyle = arguments[6];
      arguments[0].beginPath();
      arguments[0].moveTo(arguments[1],arguments[2]);
      arguments[0].arc(
      arguments[1],
      arguments[2],
      arguments[3],
      arguments[4],
      arguments[5]
    );
    arguments[0].closePath();
    arguments[0].fill();
    }
  }

var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var myCanvas_width = myCanvas.scrollWidth;
var myCanvas_height = myCanvas.scrollHeight;

myCanvas.width = myCanvas_width;
myCanvas.height = myCanvas_height;

var myVinyls = {
 'Classical music':10,
 'Rock':14,
 'Pop':15,
 'Jazz':4,
 'test':6,
 'test_1':7,
 'test_2':8
};

var myPiechart = new Piechart(
 {
  canvas:myCanvas,
  data:myVinyls,
  colors:[
   "#fde23e",
   "#f16e23",
   "#57d9ff",
   "#937e88",
   '#2fe678',
   '#228888',
   '#b111c1'
  ]
 }
);
myPiechart.drawPie();
```

How to be able to detect each slice? Thank you.

**EDIT**
I have found an amazing solution for the purpose of adding hit region in the canvas and here is the link: [Anton Lavrenov](https://blog.lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8)

Comment: Canvas is just bitmaps, so anything drawn onto it, is  not a seperate object. You need to store the size of each element you draw and its x/y position and compare any clicks with those coordinates. Or alternatively, use SVG instead of canvas so you have actual seperate elements you can click, add events to, style etc.

Comment: thank u for the comment, I know that SVG is better for events because they are elements in the DOM, but canvas is moch more better in performence. So I am trying to do it with the canvas. your tip is actually helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there are no elements on canvas you should understand this. It is a 2d plane where things are just drawn and if you want to move things around you need to redraw them entirely.

This said lets go back to the original problem.

Since you create the "object" in the canvas you know the size and distances of the object which you should keep in some js object for later use.
what i would do in this case to have an object that will hold the data of all other objects so when you click on the canvas you can get the click `x and y` and determine whether they are greater or equal to any of your objects' `x`s and `y`s
 an example algorithm would be

```
if click.X>elem.X && click.X<elem.X+elem.Width
 {
    x is in check the same for y
 }
if x__in&&y__in
  {
    you clicked the element
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes when i said element i meant the shapes. now to get the x and y (coordinates) of the click point in the canvas i should subtract the height or the width from the offset coordinates, right? or there is other easier way?

Comment: you can compare it to the elem x and y so an example would be 

if click.X>elem.X && click.X<elem.X+elem.Width{ x is in check the same for y}
@MahranSarko